# No console output from any "docker run" invocation

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

While working on docker on windows following official documentation.
I ran the standard image hello-world and it worked fine first time and also tried other images as per tutorial(python program of hello world).

But after few days when I am trying to run those images again its not running giving no output on console.

[image]

It will be great if you could also suggest me where to look for logs for whats happening in background.

Following are the commands which I am using.
- docker images ls
- docker run hello-world

Comment: In general, it's preferable to paste transcripts as text rather than screenshots. (The Windows terminal *does* support copy/paste, so these can be created rather easily). Textual transcripts are searchable, accessible by folks using screen readers or other assistive technologies, work even when sites such as imgur are blocked by corporate firewalls, etc.

Comment: Totally agree.. the reason I included screen shot because I wanted to show the output which in this case is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted system and every image started executing.

Still dont know exact error which resulted in this situation.

Please suggest where to look for logs in case you know.